# unable to login root after cis hardening

Tags: server, 22.04, login, authentication

after i follow cis 5.4.2 Ensure lockout for failed password attempts is configured to configure faillock and after reboot i unable to login root or other account.

this is my conf

```
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth   required        pam_faillock.so preauth
# Added to enable faillock
auth   [default=die]   pam_faillock.so authfail
# Added to enable faillock
auth   sufficient      pam_faillock.so authsucc
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

under /varlog/secure error
login[960]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'root', Permission denied

Comment: Ubuntu don't have root login enabled by default. Log in as your normal user and use 'sudo' to gain superuser rights.

Comment: i already reset the pw for root also able to login before apply the cis hardening